Using pint and scipy.integrate.quad
I'm trying to take a finite integral where all of my parameters and limits have units associated with them defined using pint. When I try to take the integral using scipy.integrate.quad I error out (code and error below). Is pint not able to go through an integral at this time? Other than removing my units and then adding them back in after the integral is there a way around this?
def f(x,y):
    return x
dx=quad(f,0*ureg.nm,1*ureg.nm)
print(dx[0])

DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from 'nanometer' to 'dimensionless'



What's the full error message? I believe quad is set up to work with plain dimensionless floats as the bounds and integration variable.

The full error may tell us what quad is doing the requires a dimensionless value.  Maybe it's min or a<b or b<=np.inf or ...

The problem is that scipy.quad internally calls a lot of subroutines that assume dimensionless inputs, including tolerance and error control. Pass the arguments to the function as dimensionless and convert after the result, i.e.
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

def f(x, y):
    return x

def integrate_f(a, b, units=ureg.dimensionless):
  return quad(a, b, args=(None,))[0] * (units)**2

print(integrate_f(0 , 1, units=ureg.nm))
>> 0.5 nanometer

Edit: if you want a generic function you can do something like:
def integrate(f, a, b, y=None, x_units=ureg.dimensionless, y_units=ureg.dimensionless):
  return quad(f, a, b, args=(y,))[0] * x_units * y_units

a, b = 0, 1
x_units = ureg.nm
y_units = f(0 * x_units, None).units
print(y_units)
print(integrate(f, 0 , 1, x_units=ureg.nm, y_units=y_units))
>> nanometer
>> 0.5 nanometer ** 2


Those units aren't correct: the integral of x is 1/2*x^2, so the result should have units of nanometer^2. In general, they will depend on f(x), which I assume is why the asker is concerned with units in the first place.

You are right. Fixed and added example for generic units
